# what are the openVAS9 dependecies {other than debian based linux }like "Linux From Scratch " how do you calculate?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, compiling, gentoo, dependencies

there are 4 packages in the source , which one to compile first, i mean what is the order of compilation?

*.tar.gz packages names

- Libraries 9.0.1
- Scanner 5.1.1
- Manager 7.0.2
- Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) 7.0.2

how to know the dependencies packages??  there are so many articles on debian based distros, but not one in Arch,gentoo,other distros !!??

Comment: Given the order of the list, my initial assumption would be to compile in the listed order. Have you read the README and INSTALL files? Run the configure scripts? If not, these actions should provide more clarity. As an aside, one does not typically install directly from source in Arch. Instead, make a PKGBUILD and use `makepkg`. The [official Arch repositories](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/openvas/) list the entire set of dependencies for each

Comment: knowing  dependencies then only anybody can do PKGBUILD then makepkg ??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The first half of my comment was regarding ways to discover dependencies. The second half was Arch-specific practices, and the last sentence was an aside, noting that Arch has binary version of these packages, and that these binary versions explicitly list their dependencies. You can use this list as a guide if you decide to make your own PKGBUILD

Comment: guys did you see the version, its still not available in arch, so i want to compile itby myself

Comment: That is why I suggested using the Arch binary packages as a guide, rather than simply installing them

Comment: yes, i want to make a package using PKGBUILD, but i having difficulty in finding dependency packages, to make it happend. before i can create a pkgbuild ,i wan to compile it successfully,

Answer (score 0):

First of all... you need to follow the OpenVAS instructions on their website:

> For installation from source code, it is recommended and assumed that you are familiar with the procedure to build and install software starting with the actual source code.

If you are not familiar with compiling from source, then you need to learn it first before to try to compile OpenVas...

Now, that this has been said...

The normal compiling workflow is to first have the libraries installed, then the Scanner, then the Manager and last the Greenbone Security Assistant ( that's why they have listed it in that specific way)

From your sources:

Libraries:

1) You need to read the INSTALL file which says:

> Prerequisites for openvas-libraries
>
> ...
>
> General build environment:
>
> ...

Scanner:

Repeat step 1)

Manager:

Repeat step 1)

Greenbone Security Assistant

Repeat step 1)

Everything is in the sources, all you need to do is to read them.